# Code doesn't work with all the possibilities

Tags: c++

The problem is as follows:
Basically a guy is planting oranges and from a one seed there can only grow 2 seeds, first after *x* months, and the second after *x + y*. He plants it as soon as it grows up. I need to calculate how much seeds will grow in *N* months, the problem is with this code I don't get all the answers right. All I know is that I get answers right when there's a small number, but I don't get it right with a bigger number and I have no ways knowing which ones, and I have no idea where the problem might be.

```
#include<iostream>
long int xKelias(long int N, int x); //x route, counts all oranges assuming the route will be only x till the n from i giving point
long int yKelias(long int N, int y); //same with the y
//doing this just for sake of cleaner code

int main() {    
    int x, y;
    long int N; //months
    long long int suma = 0; //total amount of oranges

    std::cin >> x >> y >> N;
    y = y + x; //simplifying 
    suma += xKelias(N, x) - 1; // adding the x route
    bool yra = true;
    while (yra) 
    {
        yra = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < xKelias(N, x); i++)
        {
            if (N - i*x > 0)
            {
                suma += yKelias(N - i*x, y) - 1;//y route from every other point of x route
                yra = true;
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < yKelias(N, y); j++)
            {
                if ((N - i*x) - y*j > 0)
                {
                    suma += xKelias((N - i*x) - y*j, x) - 1;// x route from every y route that is from x
                    yra = true;
                }               
            }
        }
        N = N - y - x; // lowering N minimum amount and repeating
    }
    std::cout << suma << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
long int xKelias(long int N, int x) {
    long int suma = 0;
    suma += N / x + 1;
    return suma;
}
long int yKelias(long int N, int y) {
    long int suma = 0;
    suma += N / y + 1;
    return suma;
}
```

Comment: Step through the program with the debugging software that came with your development environment. Keep an eye out for the program doing something you don't expect as this will likely be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem so please correct me if I'm wrong and maybe then I could find another solution. Anyway, here is what I've got. The way I see it is that you have a problem which is recursive in its nature so I would start with a simple recursive function and then look for a solution that doesn't lead to stack overflow.

```
long int seeds_count(long int x, long int y, long int N) {
    if(N < x) {
        // There's no time for the seed to grow and give any new seeds so the result is zero.
        return 0;
    } else if(x <= N && N < x + y) {
        // There is enough time for the seed to give one new seed but it's too little time for the other seed to appear - which is the '1' in the result. Also, the new seed may still have enough time give us a few other seeds - that's the recursive call to seeds_count.
        return 1 + seeds_count(x, y, N - x);
    } else {
        // This case is a sum of the result from the previous case (because the first seed has enough time to appear and maybe to grow some other seeds), one more seed (the second seed that grew from the starting seed) and the number of seeds (if any) that grew from the second seed.
        return 2 + seeds_count(x, y, N - x) + seeds_count(x, y, N - x - y);
    }
}
```